# How to purposely abandon object for garbage collection. (Java)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, finalize

So I'm writing my own 3D engine. I keep objects I loaded from an OBJ file inside of an array list. The problem is when I remove the object from the list, it doesn't get garbage collected. It may still be referenced somewhere in the code but it's a pain in the neck to search for. So I was wondering if there is a way to lock up the object when I deleted it so that it'll throw an error whenever something tries to access it.
A high poly mesh can take up to a few hundred megabytes in memory.
Thanks. (I don't want to post the code because it's pretty colossal)

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with an extra level of dereference. Rather than storing your `BigObject` in a collection, store an "envelope" for the object, and add a `release()` operation to drop the only reference to the actual object:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void usefulOperation();
}
class VeryBigObject implements MyInterface {
    public void usefulOperation() {
        ...
    }
}
class BigObjectEnvelope implements MyInterface {
    private MyInterface inner = new VeryBigObject();
    public void usefulOperation() {
        inner.usefulOperation();
    }
    public void release() {
        inner = null;
    }
}
```

Make a collection of `BigObjectEnvelope` objects, and use them through their `MyInterface` interface. When you are done with the object, call `release()` on it. Even if you have other references to `BigObjectEnvelope` in other places, calling `usefulOperation()` on it would throw an exception.

Comment: Very interesting idea. It's like manually implementing the tombstone technique. I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove an object from memory when it is still being referenced.

The most you could do is remove or minimize its internal state, if the object is structured that way. For example, you can call `clear()` on Collections, and that will remove all elements from the collection, making it a lot smaller. In your case, I suppose you could add a "invalidate" method that does something like that (although it is probably a weird design, it would really be preferable to figure out where the object is still being used and why).

Answer (score -1):

If you have a container, add an object, then remove the object, you now no longer have a reference to said object.

If you're REALLY worried about the reference, or if you made copies of it, then just implicitly `= null` them.

"the error" thrown would be the now null-pointer should you still have a reference to it. (but if you really mean to remove it, you shouldn't)

Comment: The object is not really in any container. When it's created, it's stored inside of the ArrayList. I do noticed that it has a reference to a mesh which also has a reference back at the object. It may not be collected because of the reference loop.

Comment: @JackLe Any readonably modern JVM that is commonly used has a garbage collector that can handle reference loops.

Comment: @JackLe Garbage collection handles cycles by definition. Java has done so since the beginning.

Comment: @JackLe by container I meant anything to hold objects... as an ArrayList is. And yes as others have said JVM handles reference loops should they be no longer actually used.

Comment: I tried using the "Find reference" feature in netbeans and it couldn't find and reference but it still exists somewhere in the memory. Proof is that the program still munches up a whole gigabyte in memory (using task manager).

Comment: @JackLe ... You sure its not just your IDE? My eclipse takes up 1GB+ on idle. As well sometimes gc takes a while to take effect. Whether you suggest it or not it could still take its sweet time in starting.

Comment: @MitchWeaver Yes I'm sure. Netbeans has its own instance. And I can see the memory going up by loading a rather big object in.